# Can't write to Firebase database using rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a rule that allows some users to write but not all.

I need that all user can read 'menu' items but only users listed at store data can write.

My data structure:

```
{
    "category" : [ null, "Burger", "Drinks" ],
    "menu" : [ null, {
        "available" : true,
        "category" : "1",
        "description" : "item1 description",
        "image" : "chicken_maharaja",
        "name" : "New Chicken Maharaja",
        "price" : 1300,
        "store" : 1
    }, {
                   "available" : true,
                   "category" : "1",
                   "description" : "item2 description",
                   "image" : "big_spicy_chicken_wrap",
                   "name" : "Big Spicy Chicken Wrap",
                   "price" : 120,
                   "store" : 1
               }, {
                   "available" : true,
                   "category" : "2",
                   "description" : "item3 description",
                   "image" : "thumsup",
                   "name" : "Thumsup 100ml",
                   "price" : 40,
                   "store" : 1
               }, {
                   "available" : true,
                   "category" : "2",
                   "description" : "item4 description",
                   "image" : "mccafe_ice_coffee",
                   "name" : "Ice Coffee",
                   "price" : 140,
                   "store" : 1
               }, {
                   "available" : true,
                   "category" : "1",
                   "description" : "item5 description",
                   "image" : "mc_chicken",
                   "name" : "MC Chicken",
                   "price" : 190,
                   "store" : 1
               }, {
                   "available" : true,
                   "category" : "2",
                   "description" : "item6 description",
                   "image" : "Smoothie",
                   "name" : "Smoothie",
                   "price" : 70,
                   "store" : 2
               }, {
                   "available" : true,
                   "category" : "1",
                   "description" : "item8 description",
                   "image" : "salad_wrap",
                   "name" : "Salad Wrap",
                   "price" : 150,
                   "store" : 2
               } ],
    "stores" : [ null, {
        "location" : "Campinas - Taquaral",
        "name" : "Store 1",
        "user" : {
            "pyixsRTw9qdiuESt62YnmEYXQt13" : true
        }
    }, {
                     "location" : "São Paulo - Perdises",
                     "name" : "Store 2",
                     "user" : {
                         "LBNZ8Dwp2rdJtlSh0NC1ApdtbAl2" : true,
                         "TLomOgrd3gbjDdpDAqGiwl0lBhn2" : true
                     }
                 } ],
    "userProfile" : {
        "LBNZ8Dwp2rdJtlSh0NC1ApdtbAl2" : {
            "birthDate" : "1974-02-10",
            "email" : "asd@asd.com",
            "firstName" : "João",
            "lastName" : "Silva"
        },
        "pyixsRTw9qdiuESt62YnmEYXQt13" : {
            "birthDate" : "1974-02-10",
            "email" : "leandro.garcias@gmail.com",
            "firstName" : "Leandro",
            "lastName" : "Garcia"
        }
    }
}
```

My rule:

```
{
"rules": {
    "menu": {
        "$items": {
            ".read":  "true",
            ".write": "root.child('stores').child('1').child(data.child('user').val()).hasChild(auth.uid)"
        }
    },
    "stores": {
        "$store": {
            ".read":  "true",
            ".write": "root.child('stores').child('$store').child(data.child('user').val()).hasChild(auth.uid)"
        }
    }
}
}
```

The read is ok. :-) But I can't write.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that fails to write. Hard-coded paths and values are appreciated (see [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Hi, Frank. I'm using the validate tool at Firebase console. I din't write any code yet.

Comment: Good to know. In that case, please add a screenshot of the simulator that shows the existing JSON, the path you write to, the data you're writing, and the auth data you're using.

Comment: Use this link: https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/0p243V1p001q173J0I13/Image%202017-04-07%20at%203.44.00%20PM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `newData` doesn't have a child `user` so that check always fails. You probably mean:

```
"43268522": {
  "menu": {
    "$items": {
        ".read":  "true",
        ".write": "root.child('stores').child('1').child('user').hasChild(auth.uid)"
    }
  }
```

You're probably looking for this rule:

```
".write": "
  root.child('stores')      
      .child(newData.child('store').val())
      .child('user')
      .hasChild(auth.uid)"
```

So this uses the `store` property from the new data to look up if the current user is in the store they're trying to modify.

Unfortunately this rule won't work with your current data structure, since the value of `store` is a number, while the key of a store is a string: `"1" !== 1`.

The simplest solution is to store the store as a string, e.g.:

```
"store": "1"
```

You might want to consider that anyway, since you're now getting Firebase's array coercion, which is not helpful. For more on this see our blog post on [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). I'd recommend storing stores using either [push IDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data), or simply prefixing them, e.g.

```
"stores": {
  "store1": {
    ...
  }
}
```